# not save bootstrap date value to tha DB table in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm using a bootstrap date picker in my form to save date value in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign          = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority        = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate  = $request->input('date');
    $task->save();
}
```

This is form date picker

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar">
            </i>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is jQuery function regarding with bootstrap date picker in app.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  var options={
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
  };
  date_input.datepicker(options);
})
</script>
```

Save other form date without date value in my table duedate column save with 0000-00-00 values. How can I solve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because you have set date format `format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',` like this and mysql date datatype accepts only `Y-m-d` format so you can change the format of date in datetime picker or change using `Carbon` or `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")))` function

Comment: did it but same result

Comment: check output with `dd()` and check datatype of that date column

Comment: datatype is date in date date column

Comment: did you try this `echo $request->input('date');`?

Comment: occurred this error syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: soory little bit mistake your date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date"))) solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already got it sorted but since you are already using laravel just utilize the Carbon package and it will be super simple. plus the Carbon parser is pretty good and if you ever change the way you submit the data from the front end you don't have to worry about updating your code base

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function store(Request $request)
{
...
$task->duedate  = (new Carbon($request->input('date')))->toDateString();
...
```